# Understanding the proof

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-forms

If Γ has finite in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ , show that there are only finitely
many $\Gamma$-  inequivalent elliptic points .

Proof . Suppose that $z \in \mathbb{H}$  is an elliptic point for $\Gamma$ .
 By the definition of a fundamental domain, there exists $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\gamma z$ in $F$ ,  where $F$
is the standard fundamental domain for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ . It is easily verified that $\Gamma_{\gamma z}=\gamma \Gamma_z \gamma^{-1}\neq \lbrace \pm I\rbrace$ . Hence $\gamma z$ is an elliptic point for $\Gamma$ and hence also for  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ .  We see that z is 
$SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $-equivalent to either $i$ or $\rho$ .

Let $\gamma_1,...\gamma_d$   be a complete set of coset representatives for $\Gamma $ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ .

We deduce that z is $\Gamma$-equivalent to an element of the finite set $$ \lbrace \gamma_j(i),\gamma_j(\rho):1\leq j\leq d \rbrace$$

I do not understand the last part why we consider a complete set of representatives and at the end  the deduction .

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

The elliptic points of $\Gamma \setminus \Bbb{H}$ are of the form $\Gamma z$,

$SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\Gamma z = SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) z$ is an elliptic point of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) \setminus \Bbb{H}$

so $ SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) z =  SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) i$ or $ SL_2(\Bbb{Z}) e^{2i \pi / 3}$,

$\gamma z  =  i$ or $ e^{2i \pi / 3}$ for some $\gamma \in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$

$\Gamma z  = \Gamma \gamma^{-1} i$ or $ =\Gamma \gamma^{-1} e^{2i \pi / 3}$ for some $\gamma \in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ ie. $\Gamma \gamma^{-1}  \in \Gamma \setminus SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ and the elliptic points of  $\Gamma \setminus \Bbb{H}$ are contained in the finite set $$\bigcup_{\Gamma \gamma^{-1}  \in \Gamma \setminus SL_2(\Bbb{Z})} \Gamma \gamma^{-1}i \ \cup \ \Gamma \gamma^{-1} e^{2i \pi / 3}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I do not understand the second point $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\Gamma z=SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) z$ is an elliptic point of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{H}$